# incompatible types: Editable cannot be converted to char[] when trying to get the text from text inputs

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to get the text out of text edits and am running into a problem where it says they the editable cannot be converted to char. I am guessing that there is some wrong datatype somewhere but I am unsure. the part that pertains to this code is to get values out of these text Layouts for comparison to a database for a login system.

```
public class registerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextInputEditText textInputEditTextName,textInputEditTextEmail, textInputEditTextUsername, textInputEditTextPassword;
    Button btnRegister;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
  //here  
            textInputEditTextName = findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            textInputEditTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
            textInputEditTextUsername = findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
            textInputEditTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

//to here
            btnRegister =findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fullname, password, username, email;

//here
                    fullname = String.copyValueOf(textInputEditTextName.getText());
                    email = String.copyValueOf(textInputEditTextEmail.getText());
                    username = String.copyValueOf(textInputEditTextUsername.getText());
                    password = String.copyValueOf(textInputEditTextPassword.getText());
//to here
```

I am getting the error at the parts I indicated between the comments //here,//to here.
the error lies with the names of the TextInputLayouts which I declared just under the start of the class.

[new complete error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuEet.png)

[picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQGax.png)

and this is my complete activity_register.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".registerActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FlyBy"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.095" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="full name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Username"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtEmail" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUsername" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.527" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPassword"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.112" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnToLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="already have an account?"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnRegister" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the String value of the view with the following.

```
fullname = textInputEditTextName.getText().toString();
```

Edit for a follow up question:

Read that error message and try to understand what it's telling you:

```
unexpected implicit cast to textInputEditText: Layout tag was editText
```

Look at your LayoutFile. The views you are using for name, username, password and email are "EditText".

However back in your activity class, you aren't instantiating these fields with EditText, but rather TextInputEditText. That's what the tooltip error is trying to tell you.

Change the following line from:

```
TextInputEditText textInputEditTextName,textInputEditTextEmail, textInputEditTextUsername, textInputEditTextPassword;
```

to:

```
EditText textInputEditTextName,textInputEditTextEmail, textInputEditTextUsername, textInputEditTextPassword;
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, but I think its the top block which gives me the problem and thats the one where i link the textInputEditTextName to the actual textinputLayout, the one that looks like this         textInputEditTextName = findViewById(R.id.txtName); but ill try to get the string value with your method in my second block as its easier to understand compared to the one i have.

Comment: Can you add the full error and also your R.layout.activity_register xml?

Comment: will do ill edit my origional question.

Comment: After reviewing your layout file and error message. I still agree with my original answer. You are missing .toString() when you are trying to set your string values. Currently you are only getting the reference with .getText(). Which is not a datatype of string.

Comment: thank you that did clear up alot of my errors and have replaced screenshot of my first block that still has errors and their specific errors in the second screenshot.

Comment: Use the IDE to help you determine what it's unhappy about. You can do two things. Hover your cursor over an area with the a red line. Most times a tool tip will pop up to tell you what the error is about. Option two, if you click on an area with a red line, a red lightbulb will popup at the beginning of the line. Click on the red lightbuld will sometimes give you autocomplete options to fix the error.
What does the tool tip tell you when you hoover over the red line?

Comment: it says "unexpected implicit cast to textInputEditText: Layout tag was editText", and when i click the red lightbulb it says give feedback on this error. i also had a look and my button works when i try to find it using that way its just a problem with the editTexts. this is the code used for the button:  btnRegister =findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);.